# Can i make a link inactive in css?

Tags: html, css, ruby

I have a list of events and for some reason the name of my first event in the list appears as a link. I do not have a `link_to` or `a href` tag and there's nothing else I can think of that would cause the event to be a link...there are no related divs or styles. So I am trying to mask the problem for the moment by making making it inactive but with the code

```
.inactivate {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

the name of my first event still appears as an active link 
My html

```
<% @events.each do |e| %>
<div class="wrp">
<div class="otw">
<div class="edate">
<span class="strf"><%= e.created_at.strftime("%b").to_s %></span>
<span class="strf"><%= e.created_at.strftime("%d").to_s %></span>
<span class="strf"><%= e.created_at.strftime("%Y").to_s %></span>
</div>
<div class="otr">
<span class="inactivate"><%= e.name %></span>
<%= link_to "Tables View", event_path(e)%>
<%= link_to "Reservations", event_reservations_path(e)%>
<%= link_to "Guestlist", event_guestlists_path(e)%>
<%= link_to "Manage Inventory", event_path(e)%>
<%= link_to "Promote", event_path(e)%><br>

</div>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

I am using a span class "inactivate", but I can't get it working. Any suggestions?

the generated html is

```
<div class="otw">
    <a href="events/new">
        <div class="edate">
            <span class="strf">Feb</span>
            <span class="strf">02</span>
            <span class="strf">2017</span>
        </div>
    </a>
    <div class="otr">
        <a href="events/new">
            <span class="non">mjq wednesday</span>
        </a>
        <a href="/events/1">Tables View</a>
        <a href="/events/1/reservations">Reservations</a>
        <a href="/events/1/guestlists">Guestlist</a>
        <a href="/events/1">Manage Inventory</a>
        <a href="/events/1">Promote</a><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

and it shows an `a href="events/new"`. The only place i have that a tag is in a navbar i have

```
<div>
<ul class="uni">
   <li class="evn"><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
   <li><div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
      <% @venus.each do |v| %>
      <%= link_to v.name, venue_path(v) %>
      <% end %>
  </div>
</li>
   <li class="uli"><a href="#news">News</a></li>
   <li class="uli"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
   <li class="uli"><a href="events/new">Add New Event</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

but the two are not connected in anyway..?

Comment: Can you please add the generated HTML code to your question? That should help figuring out whats going on

Comment: @Karim, added the generated code...there is a navbar above the Event List and the link is the same as one of my items in the navbar...but it has a completely different class.

Comment: The `a` tag with the `events/new` link is generated in couple of places, which is really strange. Make sure that the view is not conflicting with another view, other than this I'm not sure what might be the problem

Comment: Double checked everything, still not sure. Possiblly a bug in my cloud 9 IDE is the only thing i can think of, as that's happened before. I'll give it a try on my local server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might missing a closing anchor tag on this line:

```
<li class="uli"><a href="events/new">Add New Event</li>
```

This may be causing your browser to render the anchor tag multiple times *inside* each block element that it encounters, until the tag is closed, or the end of the page.

Answer (score 0):

That should work, although that's ugly solution:

```
.inactivate {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: /* some common color */
}
.inactivate:hover {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: /* some common color */
}
.inactivate:active {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: /* some common color */
}
```

Eventually you can try if all lines in code above are really necessary for you, maybe they aren't.